# Sharpness of Canon 80d

Tags: video, video-quality, video-recording, canon

I am trying to figure out the sharpness while shooting video with the Canon 80d. I find that the video kind of never appears to be in focus. If I take pictures of the same things the image quality and sharpness is fantastic. It's just the video that bothers me. I should say that I am speaking about 1080p video.

Is the video from a Canon 80d low quality? Maybe due to a low bitrate or something? Is it the codec that messes up the video sharpness? Is there a software setting for sharpening up the videos to get the same sharpness as with photos? Is there maybe such a feature within Magic Lantern?

Comment: If it's a matter of quality, maybe you are using a too high ISO/gain? Keep it to the very minimum (I guess ISO 100, or gain 0db), set the shutter as slow as possible (equal to the fps, so 1/25 if you are shooting at 25fps), use the iris to manage the light and only at that point dare to higher the ISO/gain if the picture isn't clear enough.

Comment: @ilmietitore Slow shutter produces lots of blur. To obtain sharp frames shutter speed must be shorter.

Comment: True, but that depends a lot on the kind of content that the author is planning to film. Certain situations won't produce a perceivable amount of blur, while in other case (such as filming a panorama) an higher blur might even be preferrable. From what I understood, the real issue here is about the overall image quality, and I'm suggesting it might be caused from a too high ISO/gain.

Comment: By the way, a screenshot might help us in determining what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

If the stills look sharp and detailed, then the sensor and optics are not to blame. I would blame the encoder and whatever sacrifices Canon made for the video mode. The 80d has the same Digic 6 processor as the older and cheaper models like the T6i.

I have an older model T4i, and it is very low-res in 1080p mode, while in 720p mode it is chock full of aliasing, completely unusable. I presume Canon improved its cameras, yet Canon DSLRs are not known for being particularly detailed when used for video, you will be better off with a Sony or a Panasonic.